# Need help in Decryption

Tags: encryption

I have been given a problem to decrypt this text:

```
3e47b75000b0924b6c9ba5759a7cf15d
```

which is supposedly an encrypted password stored in a database.

In the hint it says:"Find out what is the most common encryption used for storing passwords online. Use that to decrypt the password."

I tried some algorithm like Base64 etc but failed to decipher it.

Any suggestion or the solution to this.

Comment: Got the answer.I just googled the ciphered text and found that its an MD5 hash of "nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the password 'nothing' hashed using MD5. I found the answer using an [online MD5 plaintext/hash database](http://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=3e47b75000b0924b6c9ba5759a7cf15d).

Verfification on the command line:

```
$ echo -n nothing | md5sum.exe
3e47b75000b0924b6c9ba5759a7cf15d *-
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important that you understand the difference between hashing and encryption. That string is **not** encrypted. It's hashed, which means that it cannot be reversed to the original string (as opposed to if it were encrypted). So either you or your teacher has phrased the question wrong.

Comment: Actually this question is part of an intra college competition where questions are developed by senior students, such ambiguous question are bound to happen in such events.

Comment: @gkt.pro, ok that explains it then. It's still important to understand the difference though :-)